# Importing Module & Passing All Methods & Atrributes Via 1 Object

Tags: python, class, merge, attributes

*Hey Guys,*

I have a question about the realization of my application. Namely I would like to achieve that a module is loaded with the help of `importlib( )` and can output ALL methods & attributes in one object. I have the following
File 'sample.py', which needs to be imported :

```
from Modules import Module_Loader
   
class myapp :

    def __init__( Self , *Args , **KWT_Args ) :
        
        print( f"[  DEBUG  ] Initializing Class '{__class__.__name__}'" )   
        Self.Test = "TESTER"
        
    def Calculate( Self ) :
        print( "Calculating" )

class Testumgebung :

    Nothing = "NOTHING"

    def __init__( Self , *Args , **KWT_Args ) :
        
        print( f"[  DEBUG  ] Initializing Class 'Testumgebung'" )
        Self.OtherVar = "Anderes"
        
    def Neu( Self ) :
    
        Self.Probe = "NEUES"
```

Now I want to load this module in my application and use both the methods 'myapp( )'
& 'TestEnvironment( )' as well as the attributes `Self.Test` , `Nothing` & `OtherVar`
via a single object. For this I wrote the following module loader,
respectively 2 versions :

```
import importlib

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
class Module_Loader( ) :

    __Instance = None

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    
    def __new__( Self , *Args , **KWT_Args ) :      
        
        if Self.__Instance is None :
                     
            Self.__Instance = super( ).__new__( Self )       

        return Self.__Instance
    
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    
    def __init__( Self  ) :
    
        pass

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    def Performer_Instance( Self ) :

        Module_Specs = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location( 'sampler' , 'sampler.py' )     
        Module_Instance = importlib.util.module_from_spec( Module_Specs )
        
        Module_Specs.loader.exec_module( Module_Instance )

        return( Module_Instance )

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    def Performer_Attributes( Self ) :
                    
        Module_Specs = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location( 'sampler' , 'sampler.py' )     
        Module_Instance = importlib.util.module_from_spec( Module_Specs )
        
        Module_Specs.loader.exec_module( Module_Instance )
        
        Module_Attributes = getattr( Module_Instance , 'myapp' )( ) 

        return( Module_Attributes )
```

If I now load the module loader, e.g. via a start script, I have either the
possibility to call `Performer_Instance( )`, but then I have to load the individual
load the single class :

## start.py

```
import Modules

Test = Modules.Module_Loader( )

example = Test.Performer_Instance( )

myapp = example.myapp( )
Testumgebung = example.Testumgebung( )

myapp.Calculate( )
print( myapp.Test )
print( Testumgebung.Nothing )
print( Testumgebung.OtherVar )

Testumgebung.Neu( )
```

If I call ´´´Performer_Attributes( )```, I can call the methods & attributes in a simple way,
but it loads the individual classes, methods & attributes only from ``myapp( )''.

```
import Modules

Test = Modules.Module_Loader( )

example2 = Test.Performer_Attributes( )

example2.Calculate( )
print( example2.Test )

try :
    example2.Testumgebung( )
except AttributeError :
    print( f"'Testumgebung( )' Could Not Be Found, Because It's Not Inside Of 'myapp( )'" ) 
    
try :
    print( example2.OtherVar )
except AttributeError :
    print( f"'The Variable 'OtherVar' Could Not Be Found, Because It's Not Inside Of 'myapp( )'" )
```

I realize that this can't work, because `Module_Attributes = getattr( Module_Instance , 'myapp' )( )` refers directly to the class `myapp( )`.

How can i pass all classes, methods & attributes of a module in one object ?

Thanks in advance !

NumeroUnoDE

Comment: Unfortunately, i have to bother you again to help me with this issue, as it's important to get the right mechanism for my application. :)